# java.io.IOException when using Retrofit with rxandroid

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I need to make HTTP DELETE request to my server with body provided.

I build the retrofit object in the following way:

```
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonUTCDateAdapter())
                .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new GsonLocalDateAdapter())
                .create();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.API_BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

My Retrofit service method is:

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "selfie/{publicId}/action/1", hasBody = true)
Observable<SimpleResponseModel> unlike(
    @Path("publicId") String publicId,
    @Body AuthorisedRequestModel model
);
```

I handle retrofit request/response in following way:

```
                NetworkHelper
                .getRetrofit()
                .create(SelfieService.class)
                .unlike(selfieModel.getPublicId(), new AuthorisedRequestModel())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

                .subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<SimpleResponseModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SimpleResponseModel simpleResponseModel) {
                        ErrorHelper.handleServerError(simpleResponseModel);
                    }
                });
```

I should mention, that all another requests **GET**,**POST** and **PUT** are working, but all **DELETE** requests are return me following error, from log:

```
HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.Address@c6ec992c
```

So the request don't reach the server.

When I used Retrofit without *rxandroid* and made queries in *AsyncTask*s everything worked well.

Caused by:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=…
 at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:215)
 at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:186)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue. You can see it on GitHub:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1517

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: In most of the cases, the problem is with the server itself. You can check if the server response correctly? Try by adding some test cases when the issue rises using an empty response.